# Is attr_reader bad?

Tags: ruby, oop, getter

I'm learning ruby and my opinion about `attr_reader` is bad. Because you can change the value of particular instance variable from outside of class. For example:

```
class X
  attr_reader :some_string

  def initialize
    @some_string = "abc"
  end
end

tmp = X.new
puts tmp.some_string

tmp.some_string[0] = "aaaaaaaaa"
puts tmp.some_string
```

When you run this code you can see that the instance variable `some_string` has changed. So to avoid this I'm always making my own getter, and returning `frozen` object. For example:

```
class X
  def initialize
    @some_string = "abc"
  end

  def some_string
    @some_string.freeze
  end
end

tmp = X.new
puts tmp.some_string

tmp.some_string[0] = "aaaaaaaaa"
puts tmp.some_string
```

Now when you run the code, it throws an error saying `can't modify frozen String: "abc"`, which is what I wanted. So my question is should I use `attr_reader` and is always returning `frozen` objects from getters bad practice?

Comment: You can add `# frozen_string_literal: true` at the top of the file. https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/comments_rdoc.html#label-frozen_string_literal+Directive

Comment: I just used string to explain what I am talking about. `# frozen_string_literal: true` help only with string, but I am talking in general. @Alex

Comment: Note that `@some_string.freeze` will (first and foremost) freeze `@some_string` so even your own class won't be able to change the object afterwards. You might want to return `-@some_string` instead, see [`String#-@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#2D-40-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_reader` is not "bad",  it simply does what it does,  which is to return the value of the instance variable,  which is a reference.  Unlike `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor` it will not allow you to change the value of the instance variable (ie you can't change what the instance variable refers to)

The question is do you really want or **need** the reference.  For example say you want to convert the value of some_string to upper case.  You could use `attr_reader` to get the reference to `some_string` and then call upcase! on it like below.  But having the reference allows you to call any method on the object including the []= method which maybe you don't want to allow.  Note: []= is a method that manipulates the content of what some_string references it does **not set @some_string to a new value**, it still points to the same object,  but the object it points to was manipulated.

```rb
   class Foo
      attr_reader :some_string
    
      def initialize()
        @some_string = "abc"
      end
    end
    
    puts "Foo"
    foo = Foo.new
    some_string = foo.some_string
    puts some_string #=> abc
    some_string.upcase!
    p foo # => #<Foo:0x0000563c38391ac8 @some_string="ABC">
    puts some_string.object_id # => 60
    some_string[0] = "x"
    p foo # => #<Foo:0x0000563c38391ac8 @some_string="xBC">
    puts some_string.object_id # => 60  ... ie same object different content  
    # foo.some_string = "ABC" is a runtime error
```

If you don't want to allow arbitrary methods to be called on an instance variable then you should not expose it using `attr_reader`,  rather you should manipulate the instance variable via methods in your class.  For example below I "delegate" the upcase! method to the instance variable @some_string,  and I provide a string_value method to return a new string with the same value as the instance variable.

```rb
    class Bar
        def initialize()
            @some_string = "abc"
        end
        def upcase!()
            @some_string.upcase!
        end
        def string_value()
            "#{@some_string}"
        end
    end
    
    puts "Bar"
    bar = Bar.new
    p bar # => #<Bar:0x0000563c383915a0 @some_string="abc">
    bar.upcase!
    p bar # => #<Bar:0x0000563c383915a0 @some_string="ABC">
    some_string = bar.string_value
    p some_string # => "ABC" 
    some_string[0] = "x"
    p bar # => #<Bar:0x0000563c383915a0 @some_string="ABC">
    p some_string # => "xBC"
```

So I would say `attr_reader` is not bad,  you might argue it is over used,  I know I will often use it to "get" an instance variable when all I really need is some property on the instance variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me. I am programming in C++ for 5 years, and I learned that instance variables shouldn't be able to modify from outside of the object.

Comment: @DimitrijeCiric changing a variable (assigning a new value) and changing an object (call a mutating method) are very different things. In Ruby, many objects are mutable and it can take quite some effort to prevent that. (think of a deep structure like a hash containing arrays of strings)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of developers try to use private *attr_reader* and use it inside the class or avoid using it at all
A good conversations about *attr_reader* are [here](https://medium.com/@gabriellamedas/attr-reader-vs-instance-variables-bdb14249d396) and [here](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide/issues/538)